# How do I solve this "undefined" (reading of "...")?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, pokeapi

Ive been doing my best to get a handle on APIs and wanted to start with something that would be fun and keep my attention. I ended up going with PokeAPI, and its been cool so far. I made this along with a tutorial that started with class components, after making that functional (no pun intended), I went back and converted them to functional components. Im at the point of frustration and not understanding what Im doing wrong. So can anyone point out and explain in simple terms what I am doing wrong? And what could I do better as a beginner/ intermediate? At first I reached out on another platform for help, thinking it was me calling the API wrong somewhere. But Im starting to think it is the way Ive structured it in useState and how I am referencing it later with my HTML.

The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hp') at PkmnStats (PkmnStats.js:138:1)`

**PkmnStats**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import loading from './loading.gif';


const PkmnStats = () => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [pkmnStat, setPkmnStat] = useState([
        {
            name:'',
            index:'',
            imageUrl:'',
            types:[''],
            description:'',
            stats:{

                hp:'',
                attack:'',
                defense:'',
                speed:'',
                specialAttack:''        
            },
            height:'',
            weight:'',
            abilities:['']
        }

    ]);

    const getPkmnStats = async () => {

        const index = useParams;
        const name =  useParams;
        const pkmnUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index}/`
        const pkmnSpecies = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${index}/`

        try{
                const pkmnResponse =  await axios.get(pkmnUrl).then(() => {

                setIsLoading(true);
                const imageUrl = pkmnResponse.data.sprites.front_default;
                const species = pkmnResponse.data.species;
        
                let [ hp, attack, defense, speed, specialAttack, specialDefense] = '';
        
                pkmnResponse.data.stats.map((stat) =>  {
                    if(stat.stat.name === 'hp'){
                        hp = stat['base_stat'];
                    }
                    if(stat.stat.name === 'attack'){
                        attack = stat['base_stat'];
                    }
                    if(stat.stat.name === 'defense'){
                        defense = stat['base_stat'];
                    }
                    if(stat.stat.name === 'speed'){
                        speed = stat['base_stat'];
                    }
                    if(stat.stat.name === 'special-attack'){
                        specialAttack = stat['base_stat'];
                    }
                    if(stat.stat.name === 'special-defense'){
                        specialDefense = stat['base_stat'];
                    }
                  
    
                });
                const height = Math.round((pkmnResponse.data.height * 0.328084 + 0.0001) * 100)/100;
                const weight = Math.round((pkmnResponse.data.weight * 0.220462 + 0.0001) * 100)/100;
        
                const types  = pkmnResponse.data.types.map(types => {return types.type.name});

                const abilities = pkmnResponse.data.abilities.map(abilities => {
                return abilities.ability.name
                });
                // getPkmnDescription(pkmnSpecies);

                let description ='';

                const getDesc =  axios.get(pkmnSpecies).then(() => {

                    getDesc.data.flavor_text_entries.some(flavor => {
        
                    if (flavor.language.name === 'en') {
                        description = flavor.flavor_text;
                        return description;
                        }
                    });
                    }).catch(error => {
                        setIsLoading(false);
                        console.log("An error happened", error);
                    });
                
                
                    setPkmnStat({  index, name, imageUrl, types, stats: {hp, attack, defense, speed, specialAttack, specialDefense}, height, weight, abilities, description})

                }).catch(error => {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    console.log("An error happened", error);
                });
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
            setPkmnStat(null)

        }
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {

        getPkmnStats();
        
    },[])


    return (
            <>
            {isLoading ? (
                <div className='mx-auto w-fit h-screen p-6  md:w-3/5'>
                    <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center md:flex-col lg:flex-row'>
                            <div className='flex flex-col items-center '>
                                <p className='text-5xl md:text-6xl'>{pkmnStat.name}</p>
                                <img className=" w-32 h-32 md:w-64 md:h-64 " src={pkmnStat.imageUrl} alt={pkmnStat.name} />
                                <div className='flex flex-row '>
                                    <div>{pkmnStat[0] ? pkmnStat[0] : null}</div>
                                    <div>{pkmnStat[1] ? pkmnStat[1] :null}</div>
                                </div>
                                <p>Height: {pkmnStat.height} ft.</p>
                                <p>Weight: {pkmnStat.weight} lbs.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className='flex flex-col items-center '>
                                <p className='text-center my-5'>{pkmnStat.description} </p>
                                
                                <p>Abilities: {pkmnStat.abilities}</p>
                                <div className='flex flex-col items-center mt-4 '>
                                        <p> HP: {pkmnStat.stats.hp}</p>
                                        <p> Attack: {pkmnStat.stats.attack}</p>
                                        <p>Defense: {pkmnStat.stats.defense}</p>
                                        <p>Speed: {pkmnStat.stats.speed}</p>
                                        <p>Spec.Attack: {pkmnStat.stats.specialAttack}</p>
                                        <p>Spec.Defense: {pkmnStat.stats.specialDefense}</p>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ) : ( <img src={loading} className="mx-auto bg-platnium" alt="loading gif"/>) }
            </> 
    )
    
}
export default PkmnStats
```

Here is two more for reference:

**PkmnCard**

```
import loading from './loading.gif'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const PkmnCard = ({pokemon}) => {

    const index = pokemon.url.split('/')[pokemon.url.split('/').length - 2];
    const sprite =`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${index}.png`;
    
    return (
     
        <Link to={`/pokemon/${pokemon.name}/${index}`}>
            {pokemon ? (<div className='flex flex-col h-64  items-center p-10 rounded-xl  shadow-lg hover:shadow-2xl hover:border-stone-700 bg-white select-none '>
                <h3 className='text-center capitalize'>{pokemon.name}</h3>
                
                {pokemon.imageLoading ? (<img src={loading} className="mx-auto w-10 h-10" alt="loading gif"/>) :null}
                <img className='mx-auto' style={pokemon.tooManyRequests ? {display: "none"} : pokemon.imageLoading ? null : {display: "block"}} src={sprite} alt={pokemon.name} onLoad={() => ({imageLoading: false})} onError={ () => ({ tooManyRequests: true})} />
                {pokemon.tooManyRequests ? (<h6 className='mx-auto bg-red-600'> <span className='text-white'>Too Many Requests </span></h6>) :null }
                <h3 className="text-center">-No.{index}-</h3>
            
            </div>):  (<img src={loading} className="mx-auto bg-platnium" alt="loading gif"/>)}
        </Link>
     
    )


  
}
export default PkmnCard
```

**App**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import PkmnList from './components/PkmnList'
import PkmnStats from './components/PkmnStats'



function App (){

    return (  
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="w-full">
            <Navbar/>
          
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<PkmnList/>} />
                <Route path="/pokemon/:name/:index"  element={<PkmnStats/>} />
              </Routes>
            
          </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )


  }
export default App;
```

Any help in figuring this out and cementing this to memory is very welcome and appreciated!

Comment: when isLoading is true, you are trying to use pkmnStat but it is not loaded yet. The error is basically telling you that pkmnStat is undefined

Comment: @ariel obviously `pkmnStat` isn't undefined, otherwise we'd get the error one dot earlier: instead of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hp')", we'd have "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stats')".

Comment: @mbojko you are right. pkmnStat.stats is undefined. That's a typo. Just check why it is undefined. Maybe it is an array and not an object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pkmnStat` is an array of stats objects, not a single object, it doesn't have the `stats` property. If I follow the logic of your app correctly, you can just ditch the square brackets in `useState` here:

```
const [pkmnStat, setPkmnStat] = useState([{ /* object definition here */}])
```

and instead do

```
const [pkmnStat, setPkmnStat] = useState({ /* object definition here */})
```

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy over this to the point my head was hurting from trying figure it out. Ill remember not to use  square brackets when creating useState